# MSTest robustness

Tags: .net, unit-testing

We have a number of issues with MSTest failing randomly on a list of 300+ .NET unit test. Is MSTest robust enough for serious unit testing or we need to look for a 3rd party tool?

Thanks.

Comment: Try NUnit, it's free and easy to use.

Comment: Failing how? Do you use any IO on those tests?

Comment: Is the code in such poor shape that it bombs mstest?  Arbitrarily trying another unit tester doesn't improve that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved changing the 'Test Timeouts' settings. The default is 30 minutes that is definitely too much for our unit test and made me think about a problem in MSTest itself.